# ¿ Crear una Animación con frames de distinta duración con un Array de UIImage?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, swift3

Para crear una animación con arrays de UIImage uso UIImage.animatedImages pero solo me deja crear la animación con un valor entre frames común a todos.

UIImage.animatedImage(with: animation, duration: TimeInterval(duration))

Donde animation es un array de tipo [UIImage]

¿ Hay alguna libreria o codino donde pudiera mostrar animaciones pero entre frames con diferente duración ?

Answer (score 1):

No sé de ningún pod que haga eso se me ocurren dos opciones

1- Repetir la imagen que quieres que dure más

Ej: `[img1, img2, img3, img3, img3, img4, img5, img5]`
De esta forma la imagen 3 dura el triple que las normales y la imagen 5 el doble

2- Crear tu propio timer variando el intervalo por cada imagen.
Es más complicado pero más preciso.

Puedes un array de objetos que contengan la imagen con su respectiva duración, y en cada iteración del timer recoger la siguiente imagen y renovar el timer con su duración.

Yo siempre prefiero un array de objetos(creas un modelo sencillo) en vez de el diccionario porque este te puede desordenar los elementos que contiene

```
var indice = 0
let arrayImages = [objetoImagenYDuracion]()//lo creas en el viewDidLoad o lo cargas de algún sitio
var timer = Timer()

func cambiarImagen(){
    let objeto = arrayImages[indice]
    UIImageView().image = objeto.imagen
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: objeto.duracion, target: self, selector: #selector(self.cambiarImagen), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

    //para que funcione en bucle vuelves al índice 0
    if indice == arrayImages.count - 1{
        indice = 0
    }else{
        indice += 1
    }

}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    cambiarImagen()
}
```

Comment: Como podría hacerlo creando mi propio  timer, variando por cada imagen? Conoces algún código de ejemplo ? He intentado hacerlo con un array de UIImage.animatedImage con cada objeto animación del array con su propia duración y luego todo ello en otro UIImage.animatedImage pero no me funciona

Comment: He añadido un ejemplo a la respuesta que espero te sirva.